# Between date in Mysql not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to filter some items based on two different dates using MySQL. In my database I store data like `2017-03-28 10:55:10`. But I need only the date part, not the time so I used the `DATE()` function:

```
select sum(cashamount) as sumcashsalesamount,
       DATE(transactiondate) as datepart 
from master_transaction 
where transactiondate BETWEEN '2017-02-22%' AND '2017-03-28%' 
order by transactiondate desc
```

Above this query have two dates `2017-02-22%` and `2017-03-28%` but this return no result.

But when I change this `2017-03-28%` date to `2017-03-29%` (tomorrow date) I get results.

Comment: Where's the GROUP BY?

Comment: use date('2017-03-28 00:06:00') to extract date from datetime like this

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `between` with "dates".  I put that in quotes, because your values are really datetime values.

The best way to write this condition is:

```
where transactiondate >= '2017-02-22' and
      transactiondate < '2017-03-29'
```

Note the inequality for the second condition.  `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so it would include midnight on 2017-03-28.

Why is this best?

- It allows the query optimizer to take advantage of indexes and partitions.
- It is exactly the logic that you want.
- It works for both `date` and `datetime` types.

Comment: nice. its use full

Answer (score 2):

`BETWEEN` is inclusive on both sides, and if no time component is given for a date, it defaults to `00:00:00`. Since `2017-03-28 10:55:10` > `2017-03-28 00:00:00` it is not included in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

`2017-03-28%` = `2017-03-28 00:00:00`

If something happened during that day, you need `2017-03-28 23:59:59`, or `date_sub(2017-03-29, INTERVAL 1 second)` for ease

Answer (score 1):

You can only use wildcard characters (%) with LIKE.

Use:

```
where date(transactiondate) BETWEEN '2017-02-22' AND '2017-03-28'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use between and you want today, all day, you must put tomorrow date

Answer (score 0):

And i fix my problem

```
select sum(cashamount) as sumcashsalesamount           
from master_transaction 
where DATE(transactiondate)BETWEEN '2017-02-22' AND '2017-03-28' 
order by transactiondate desc
```

I just re-place the DATE(transactiondate) in where condition its worked